# Is it possible to run the map reduce job in oozie 4.1.0 with hadoop 2.5.2

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I am new to oozie, is possible to run the mapreduce job in **oozie 4.1.0** with **hadoop 2.5.2** .???

please guide me!

Comment: Are you having a particular problem here? Which version of Hadoop are you referring to, as you mentioned 2.5.2 and 2.6.0?

Comment: yes am using 2.5.2 !! is there any scheduler problem there? while running oozie! because once i submit the job its in accepted state only. heart beat iisue will occurs. what should i do??

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it should be memory problem. Set the below properties in yarn-site.xml and try to run job,

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>20960</value>
</property> 
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>512</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
</property>
```

Comment: yes !! already i have checked it any ways thanks for you valuable answer !